# Notifying adapter from model

Tags: android, model, adapter, mvp, notify

I'm trying to make changes to my android application by adopting the MVP pattern, but I'm having trouble with where to notify the adapter the recyclerview is using.

What I'm currently doing is giving a reference to the adapter in my model and notifying it as changes are made when click events happen, like so:

```
public class MyModel {

    private MyAdapter adapter;
    ...
    public void setAdapter(MyAdapter adapter) { this.adapter = adapter; }

    public void action() {
        // make changes to model and notify adapter as changes are 
        // made to individual items
        ...
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    }
}
```

I'm wonder what the conventional way of handling this kind of behaviour is using the MVP pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Observer pattern might be what you are looking for. When changes are made to the model you can notify the Observers (The presenters) so they can then update the view.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern